# In Angular how to transfer the data from a binary file to the front end via httpclient?

Tags: json, angular, excel, binary, base64

I need to transfer an Excel spreadsheet which includes charts and data from the backend (python) to the frontend (Angular-Javascript). To utilize the httpclient, I need to code the binary data in JSON as:

```
the_data = None
with open(output_file_path, mode='rb') as file:
    output_file = file.read()
        
    if output_file:
        binary_data = base64.encodebytes(output_file).decode('utf-8')
        the_data = {
                    'file': binary_data,
                    'name': 'export.xlsx',
                    'type': 'file'
                   }

dump_str = json.dumps(the_data)
js = json.loads(dump_str)

return js
```

Then on the front-end, I am trying to decode the data and save it to an excel file:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
...
this._service.export(request).subscribe((data:{}) => {
    const name = (data as any)['name']
    const b64Data = (data as any)['file'];
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);

    const data: Blob = new Blob([byteCharacters], { type: application/octet- stream" });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, name);
});
```

The binary stream data look close but still different, and the saved export.xlsx cannot be opened by Excel. Any one knows what is the missing step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out with hints from [Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)
The front-end should be:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
...
this._service.export(request).subscribe((data:{}) => {
    const name = (data as any)['name']
    const b64Data = (data as any)['file'];
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
       byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    const data: Blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/octet- stream" });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, name);
});
```